# Error starting ejabberd 16.05 server on Mac os 10.7.5

Tags: macos, ejabberd, post-install

I am newbie to ejabberd world. I am getting error while installation of ejabberd 15.06 server on mac os 10.7.5 during post install script execution. The installation looks to be complete. I went to bin directory of ejabberd installation path and manually executed `post_install.sh` to understand error. It is giving below error which doesn't make sense to me.

Can anyone please help?

```
./ejabberdctl: line 160:  2092 Segmentation fault: 11  $EXEC_CMD "$ERL       $NAME $ERLANG_NODE       -noinput -detached       -pa $EJABBERD_EBIN_PATH       $MNESIA_OPTS       $KERNEL_OPTS       $EJABBERD_OPTS       -s ejabberd       -sasl sasl_error_logger \\{file,\\\"$SASL_LOG_PATH\\\"\\}       $ERLANG_OPTS $ARGS \"$@\""

./ejabberdctl: line 393:  2128 Segmentation fault: 11  $EXEC_CMD "$ERL       $NAME ${CONN_NAME}       -noinput       -hidden       -pa $EJABBERD_EBIN_PATH       $KERNEL_OPTS       -s ejabberd_ctl -extra $ERLANG_NODE $COMMAND"

./ejabberdctl: line 393:  2144 Segmentation fault: 11  $EXEC_CMD "$ERL       $NAME ${CONN_NAME}       -noinput       -hidden       -pa $EJABBERD_EBIN_PATH       $KERNEL_OPTS       -s ejabberd_ctl -extra $ERLANG_NODE $COMMAND"
```

Comment: A segmentation fault usually means it's a bug in the program. Try contacting the developers.

Comment: i downloaded ejabberd server from https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/ and post installation script was giving above error. ejabberd server hasn't even started.

Comment: I just observed another weird thing on investigating further. The "erl" executable shipped with ejabberd 15.06 is giving error as "segmentation fault 11" while executing. the same executable is used to start ejabberd server so I think if anyone can tell me why "erl" is giving segmentation fault, the server not starting error will automatically be resolved.                      kartik:bin Kartik$ ./erl
Segmentation fault: 11
kartik:bin Kartik$ pwd
/Applications/ejabberd-15.06/bin

Comment: Also posted on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/641728/

Answer (score 0):

The error is a segmentation fault, which means the C Erlang binary is crashing.

The reason for this is that the build provided in the installer is not compliant with ejabberd 10.7.

You will have to build ejabberd yourself by downloading the source. You can find build instructions in [ejabberd installation documentation](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/). Please, make sure to also read the special notes related to OSX.